# The shadows are not working as intended

Tags: html, css, browser, cross-browser

If for a element whose id is A, I am applying the following box shadow based on browser:

```
#A{
box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px blue inset;
-moz-box-shadow: 3px 3px 5px red inset;
-webkit-box-shadow: 2px 2px 5px green inset;
}
```

Chrome gives the green box shadow, but Firefox doesn't. It gives a blue shadow, though it should be red.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mozilla changed the box-shadow property of Firefox since Version 4 as of March 22, 2011

[RESOURCE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Releases/4)

Comment: Thanks. They are using box-shadow as their rendering property. Hence, firefox uses the box-shadow value.